# Python Tkinter Platformer Collision

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection

so I'm working on a platformer in tkinter and I can not get the collision to consistently work without something breaking. The first Player can walk through the second one but the second one can walk through the other. The collision is done in the `Collision` function

Here's the code (*It's an old version but it has the same issue*):

```py
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
import time
import winsound

FPS = 60

SCALE_FACTOR = 95.3
MAX_VELOCITY = 5
# Constants for tile size and window size
PLAYER_SIZE = 27

# Game map
game_map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

# Player position
player_x = 250
player_x_velocity = 0

player_y = 50
player_y_velocity = 0

player2_x = 165
player2_x_velocity = 0

player2_y = 50
player2_y_velocity = 0
SPEED = 1

# Initialize tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

# Create a scrollable canvas
canvas_width = len(game_map[0]) * SCALE_FACTOR
canvas_height = len(game_map) * SCALE_FACTOR
#canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1920 , height=1080, bg="#BEDBED")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080, bg="black")
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

#scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
#scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
#canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


Floor_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Floor.png")
Floor_Sprite = Floor_Sprite.zoom(6, 6)
Brick_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Brick.png")
Brick_Sprite = Brick_Sprite.zoom(6, 6)
Bush_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Bush.png")
Bush_Sprite = Bush_Sprite.zoom(5, 5)
#--------------Ground---------------------------
Idle_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Mario2/MarIdle.png")
Idle_Sprite = Idle_Sprite.zoom(5, 5)
Jump_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Mario2/MarJump.png")
Jump_Sprite = Jump_Sprite.zoom(5, 5)
REVIdle_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Luigi/RevLuiIdle.png")
REVIdle_Sprite = REVIdle_Sprite.zoom(5, 5)
REVJump_Sprite = tk.PhotoImage(file="Luigi/RevLuiJump.png")
REVJump_Sprite = REVJump_Sprite.zoom(5, 5)
Current_Idle = Idle_Sprite
sprite_frames = []
for i in range(24):
    sprite_frame = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"Mario/MarRun/MarRun{i+1}.png")
    sprite_frame = sprite_frame.zoom(3, 3)
    sprite_frames.append(sprite_frame)

idle_frames = []

for i in range(80):
    time.sleep(1/FPS)
    idle_frame = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"Sonic/SonIdle{i+1}.png")
    idle_frame = idle_frame.zoom(3, 3)
    idle_frames.append(idle_frame)
'''
for i in range(74):
    time.sleep(1/60)
    idle_frame = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"Mario/MarIdle - Copy/MarIdle{i+1}.png")
    idle_frame = idle_frame.zoom(3, 3)
    idle_frames.append(idle_frame)    
'''
REVsprite_frames =  []
for i in range(8):
    REVsprite_frame = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"Luigi/RevLuiRun{i//2}.png")
    REVsprite_frame = REVsprite_frame.zoom(5, 5)
    REVsprite_frames.append(REVsprite_frame)

Current_Walk = sprite_frames

sprite_index = 0  # Current sprite frame index
idle_index = 0
REVsprite_index = 0
#---------------Music----------------------------
def wavsound(asynced=True):
    flags = winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC if asynced else winsound.SND_FILENAME
    winsound.PlaySound(r"Music/Mission Mode - Mario Kart DS Music Extended (128 kbps)", flags)
GroundTheme = "Mission Mode - Mario Kart DS Music Extended (128 kbps)"
#---------------Player---------------------------

def draw_map():
    for y in range(len(game_map)):
        for x in range(len(game_map[y])):
            if game_map[y][x] == 1:
                #canvas.create_rectangle(x * SCALE_FACTOR, y * SCALE_FACTOR, (x + 1) * SCALE_FACTOR, (y + 1) * SCALE_FACTOR, fill="#FFE5B4")
                canvas.create_image(x * SCALE_FACTOR, y * SCALE_FACTOR, image=Floor_Sprite)
    for y in range(len(game_map)):
        for x in range(len(game_map[y])):
            if game_map[y][x] == 2:
                
                canvas.create_rectangle(x * SCALE_FACTOR, y * SCALE_FACTOR, (x + 1) * SCALE_FACTOR, (y + 1) * SCALE_FACTOR, fill="#7DF9FF")
                
                #canvas.create_image(x * SCALE_FACTOR, y * SCALE_FACTOR, image=Brick_Sprite)

def draw_player2():
    if player2_x_velocity > 0:
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+10, player2_y-6, image=sprite_frames[sprite_index], tags="player2")
    elif player2_x_velocity < 0:
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+10, player2_y-6, image=REVsprite_frames[REVsprite_index], tags="player2")
    else:
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+10, player2_y-6, image=idle_frames[idle_index], tags="player2")
        
    if player2_y_velocity != 0:
        canvas.delete("player2")
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+11, player2_y-7, image=Jump_Sprite, tags="player2")
    if player2_y_velocity != 0 and player2_x_velocity > 0:
        canvas.delete("player2")
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+11, player2_y-7, image=Jump_Sprite, tags="player2")
    if player2_y_velocity != 0 and player2_x_velocity < 0:
        canvas.delete("player2")
        canvas.create_image(player2_x+11, player2_y-7, image=REVJump_Sprite, tags="player2")
#def collision(x, y):
 #   if canvas.find_overlapping(x - PLAYER_SIZE, y - PLAYER_SIZE, x + PLAYER_SIZE + 10, y + PLAYER_SIZE + 5):
  #      return False
   # return True
# Player position


def draw_player():
    if player_x_velocity > 0:
        canvas.create_image(player_x+10, player_y-6, image=sprite_frames[sprite_index], tags="player")
    elif player_x_velocity < 0:
        canvas.create_image(player_x+10, player_y-6, image=REVsprite_frames[REVsprite_index], tags="player")
    else:
        canvas.create_image(player_x+10, player_y-6, image=idle_frames[idle_index], tags="player")
        
    if player_y_velocity != 0:
        canvas.delete("player")
        canvas.create_image(player_x+11, player_y-7, image=Jump_Sprite, tags="player")
    if player_y_velocity != 0 and player_x_velocity > 0:
        canvas.delete("player")
        canvas.create_image(player_x+11, player_y-7, image=Jump_Sprite, tags="player")
    if player_y_velocity != 0 and player_x_velocity < 0:
        canvas.delete("player")
        canvas.create_image(player_x+11, player_y-7, image=REVJump_Sprite, tags="player")
def collision(x, y):
    if canvas.find_overlapping(x - PLAYER_SIZE, y - PLAYER_SIZE, x + PLAYER_SIZE + 10, y + PLAYER_SIZE + 5):
        return False
    return True

draw_map()
wavsound(asynced=True)
while True:
    #Player 2 Inputs and collision
    canvas.delete("player2")
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0x26):
        if not collision(player2_x, player2_y + 10):
           player2_y_velocity = -45
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0x25):
        if collision(player2_x - SPEED, player2_y):
            player2_x_velocity -= 2 * SPEED
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0x27):
        if collision(player2_x + SPEED, player2_y):
            player2_x_velocity += (2 * SPEED) 
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0xA3):
          MAX_VELOCITY = 30           

    if not ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0xA3):
          MAX_VELOCITY = 10
          
    if collision(player2_x, player2_y + player2_y_velocity + 4):
        player2_y_velocity += 4
    else:
        player2_y_velocity = 0

    if player2_x_velocity > 0:
        player2_x_velocity -= 1
    if player2_x_velocity < 0:
        player2_x_velocity += 1

    if player2_x_velocity > MAX_VELOCITY:
        player2_x_velocity = MAX_VELOCITY
    if player2_x_velocity < -MAX_VELOCITY:
        player2_x_velocity = -MAX_VELOCITY

    if collision(player2_x, player2_y + player2_y_velocity):
        player2_y += player2_y_velocity
    if collision(player2_x + player2_x_velocity, player2_y):
        player2_x += player2_x_velocity
    
    
    if player2_x > canvas_width / 2:
        scroll_x = player2_x - canvas_width / 2
    else:
        scroll_x = 0

    if player2_y > canvas_height / 2:
        scroll_y = player2_y - canvas_height / 2
    else:
        scroll_y = 1
    #Player 1 Inputs and Collision
    canvas.delete("player")
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(ord("O")):
        if not collision(player_x, player_y + 10):
           player_y_velocity = -45
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(ord("A")):
        if collision(player_x - SPEED, player_y):
            player_x_velocity -= 2 * SPEED
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(ord("D")):
        if collision(player_x + SPEED, player_y):
            player_x_velocity += (2 * SPEED) 
    if ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(ord("P")):
          MAX_VELOCITY = 30           

    if not ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(ord("P")):
          MAX_VELOCITY = 10
          
    if collision(player_x, player_y + player_y_velocity + 4):
        player_y_velocity += 4
    else:
        player_y_velocity = 0

    if player_x_velocity > 0:
        player_x_velocity -= 1
    if player_x_velocity < 0:
        player_x_velocity += 1

    if player_x_velocity > MAX_VELOCITY:
        player_x_velocity = MAX_VELOCITY
    if player_x_velocity < -MAX_VELOCITY:
        player_x_velocity = -MAX_VELOCITY

    if collision(player_x, player_y + player_y_velocity):
        player_y += player_y_velocity
    if collision(player_x + player_x_velocity, player_y):
        player_x += player_x_velocity
    
    if player_x > canvas_width / 2:
        scroll_x = player_x - canvas_width / 2
    else:
        scroll_x = 0

    if player_y > canvas_height / 2:
        scroll_y = player_y - canvas_height / 2
    else:
        scroll_y = 1

    canvas.delete("all")
    #Player 2 wraparound
    if player2_x > canvas_width:
        player2_x = 0
    if player2_x < 0:
        player2_x = canvas_width
    if player2_y > canvas_height:
        player2_y = 0
    #Player 1 wraparound 
    if player_x > canvas_width:
        player_x = 0
    if player_x < 0:
        player_x = canvas_width
    if player_y > canvas_height:
        player_y = 0
    
    

    sprite_index = (sprite_index + 1) % len(sprite_frames)
    REVsprite_index = (REVsprite_index + 1) % len(REVsprite_frames)
    idle_index = (idle_index + 1) % len(idle_frames)

    draw_map()
    draw_player()
    draw_player2()
    root.update()
    #winsound.PlaySound(GroundTheme, winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    root.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1 / FPS)
```

I tried placing the code in a different order and it didn't change anything since it still had the same player not being able to pass through

Comment: Despite many questions that arises immediately while looking at your code, like why don't you use tkinters `mainloop` or the events and why the use of `win32` at all. Your code is a little too long and complicated to see the solution on first glance to me, However, I recommend just using `collision` function once per iteration to reduce the problem to a single call.

Comment: Alright, I will try that. I had to use an older version of my code cause I post any newer versions of the code because of the exam board which this code is being used for.